# Convert std::string to FString (TCHAR / wstring) with special characters

Tags: c++, string, unreal-engine4, string-conversion, text-manipulation

Using Unreal Engine 4, I want to load a file from the machine, which contains characters like `“`, `”`, `‘` and `’`.

All conversion attempts result in the final `FString` either containing `?` in their place, or no character at all.

`FString` is UE4's internal string class, that uses `TCHAR` (`wchar_t`), which uses UTF-16 encoding.

Even desperate attempts to use this failed:

```
std::replace(str.begin(), str.end(), L'“', L'\"');
```

Nothing happened.

How can I properly convert between a `std::string` to an `FString`?

Comment: First, you need to decide what encoding the `std::string` uses. Does it use UTF-8, or a system-defined locale?  You can't convert it without answering that first. But when you do convert, you can use portable STL features like `std::wstring_convert()` or `mbsrtowcs()`, or Unicode libraries like ICONV or ICU, or platform-specific functions like `MultiByteToWideChar()` on Windows, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As it may have become obvious, I am not knowledgeable about all this, so my answers may sound stupid. We want to let user read any sort of file, so it would be nice if we could work with any (common) encoding. But I assume you mean the encoding of the string itself? When I did my research, it said that string does not use any particular encoding on it's own, just stores the bytes. How would I know which encoding it uses?

Comment: that is for you to decide when you populate the string. When you are reading files, there is no common encoding. You have to know the encoding of each file. If you don't know, you are out of luck, unless you ask the user, or use hieristics to guess.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your `std::string` to `std::wstring` as it is also templated on `wchar_t` and try initializing your `FString` with it.
Check out this topic if you don't know how to convert to `wstring`: [c++ can't convert string to wstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141848/c-cant-convert-string-to-wstring)
Then you could do something like:
`FString str = FString(your_wstring.c_str());` 
or
`FString str(your_wstring.c_str());`

You could also try to read data from file straight to `wstring` or even to `FString` because UE4 has its own classes for managing files like e.g. `FFileHelper`: http://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Core/Misc/FFileHelper/index.html and I would really recommend you this last option :-)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, I tried that already, wstring just completely discarded the characters not recognized by FString alltogether. No special '?', just not there anymore. In another conversion method, I at least now recognized a the - char, but nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert std::string to FString and than log that like this.

```
std::string someString = "Hello!";

FString unrealString(someString .c_str());

UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("%s"), *unrealString);
```

Than you can do the FString replace function on it. 
https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/Containers/FString/Replace/index.html